# How to programmatically perform fastest 'trans-wrap' of mov to mp4 on iPhone/iPad application?

Tags: ios, video, containers, mov

I want to change the container of `.mov` video files that I pick using 
`UIImagePickerController` and compressed them via `AVAssetExportSession` with `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality` and  `shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES` to `.mp4` container.

I need programmatically way/sample code to perform a fastest `trans-wrap` on iPhone/iPad application

I tried to set `AVAssetExportSession.outputFileType` property to `AVFileTypeMPEG4` but it is not supported and I got an exception.

I tried to do this transform using `AVAssetWriter` by specifying `fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4`, actually I got `.mp4` output file, but it was not `wrap-trans`, the output file was  3x bigger than source, and the convert process took `128 sec` for video with `60 sec` duration.

I need solution that will run quickly and will keep the file size

This is the code I use to convert `.mov` to `.mp4`:

I set `assetWriter` options on `setUpReaderAndWriterReturningError` method

```
#import "MCVideoConverter.h"


#import <AVFoundation/AVAsset.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAssetTrack.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAssetReader.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAssetReaderOutput.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAssetWriter.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAssetWriterInput.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVMediaFormat.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSettings.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVVideoSettings.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAssetImageGenerator.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVTime.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CMSampleBuffer.h>


@protocol RWSampleBufferChannelDelegate;

@interface RWSampleBufferChannel : NSObject
{
@private
    AVAssetReaderOutput     *assetReaderOutput;
    AVAssetWriterInput      *assetWriterInput;

    dispatch_block_t        completionHandler;
    dispatch_queue_t        serializationQueue;
    BOOL                    finished;  // only accessed on serialization queue
}

- (id)initWithAssetReaderOutput:(AVAssetReaderOutput *)assetReaderOutput assetWriterInput:(AVAssetWriterInput *)assetWriterInput;
- (void)startWithDelegate:(id <RWSampleBufferChannelDelegate>)delegate completionHandler:(dispatch_block_t)completionHandler;  // delegate is retained until completion handler is called.  Completion handler is guaranteed to be called exactly once, whether reading/writing finishes, fails, or is cancelled.  Delegate may be nil.
- (void)cancel;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *mediaType;

@end


@protocol RWSampleBufferChannelDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)sampleBufferChannel:(RWSampleBufferChannel *)sampleBufferChannel didReadSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer;
@end


@interface MCVideoConverter () <RWSampleBufferChannelDelegate>

// These three methods are always called on the serialization dispatch queue
- (BOOL)setUpReaderAndWriterReturningError:(NSError **)outError;  // make sure "tracks" key of asset is loaded before calling this
- (BOOL)startReadingAndWritingReturningError:(NSError **)outError;
- (void)readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:(BOOL)success withError:(NSError *)error;

@end


@implementation MCVideoConverter

+ (NSArray *)readableTypes
{
    return [AVURLAsset audiovisualTypes];;
}

+ (BOOL)canConcurrentlyReadDocumentsOfType:(NSString *)typeName
{
    return YES;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        NSString *serializationQueueDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ serialization queue", self];
        serializationQueue = dispatch_queue_create([serializationQueueDescription UTF8String], NULL);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [asset      release];
    [outputURL  release];

    [assetReader release];
    [assetWriter release];
    [audioSampleBufferChannel release];
    [videoSampleBufferChannel release];
    if (serializationQueue)
        dispatch_release(serializationQueue);

    [super dealloc];
}

@synthesize asset=asset;
@synthesize timeRange=timeRange;
@synthesize writingSamples=writingSamples;
@synthesize outputURL=outputURL;
@synthesize propgerssView;

- (void)convertVideo:(NSURL*) inputURL outputURL: (NSURL*) _outputURL progress:(UIProgressView*) _propgerssView
{
    self.asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    self.propgerssView = _propgerssView;

    cancelled = NO;    

    [self performSelector:@selector(startProgressSheetWithURL:) withObject:_outputURL afterDelay:0.0];  // avoid starting a new sheet while in 
}


- (void)startProgressSheetWithURL:(NSURL *)localOutputURL
{
    [self setOutputURL:localOutputURL];
    [self setWritingSamples:YES];

    AVAsset *localAsset = [self asset];
    [localAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tracks", @"duration", nil] completionHandler:^
     {
         // Dispatch the setup work to the serialization queue, to ensure this work is serialized with potential cancellation
         dispatch_async(serializationQueue, ^{
             // Since we are doing these things asynchronously, the user may have already cancelled on the main thread.  In that case, simply return from this block
             if (cancelled)
                 return;

             BOOL success = YES;
             NSError *localError = nil;

             success = ([localAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&localError] == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded);
             if (success)
                 success = ([localAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"duration" error:&localError] == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded);

             if (success)
             {
                 [self setTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [localAsset duration])];

                 // AVAssetWriter does not overwrite files for us, so remove the destination file if it already exists
                 NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                 NSString *localOutputPath = [localOutputURL path];
                 if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:localOutputPath])
                     success = [fm removeItemAtPath:localOutputPath error:&localError];
             }

             // Set up the AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter, then begin writing samples or flag an error
             if (success)
                 success = [self setUpReaderAndWriterReturningError:&localError];
             if (success)
                 success = [self startReadingAndWritingReturningError:&localError];
             if (!success)
                 [self readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:success withError:localError];
         });
     }];
}

- (BOOL)setUpReaderAndWriterReturningError:(NSError **)outError
{
    BOOL success = YES;
    NSError *localError = nil;
    AVAsset *localAsset = [self asset];
    NSURL *localOutputURL = [self outputURL];

    // Create asset reader and asset writer
    assetReader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:asset error:&localError];
    success = (assetReader != nil);
    if (success)
    {
        //changed assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:localOutputURL fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&localError];
        assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:localOutputURL fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 error:&localError];

        success = (assetWriter != nil);
    }

    // Create asset reader outputs and asset writer inputs for the first audio track and first video track of the asset
    if (success)
    {
        AVAssetTrack *audioTrack = nil, *videoTrack = nil;

        // Grab first audio track and first video track, if the asset has them
        NSArray *audioTracks = [localAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
        if ([audioTracks count] > 0)
            audioTrack = [audioTracks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *videoTracks = [localAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([videoTracks count] > 0)
            videoTrack = [videoTracks objectAtIndex:0];

        if (audioTrack)
        {
            // Decompress to Linear PCM with the asset reader
            NSDictionary *decompressionAudioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
                                                        nil];
            AVAssetReaderOutput *output = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:audioTrack outputSettings:decompressionAudioSettings];
            [assetReader addOutput:output];

            AudioChannelLayout stereoChannelLayout = {
                .mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo,
                .mChannelBitmap = 0,
                .mNumberChannelDescriptions = 0
            };
            NSData *channelLayoutAsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&stereoChannelLayout length:offsetof(AudioChannelLayout, mChannelDescriptions)];

            // Compress to 128kbps AAC with the asset writer
            NSDictionary *compressionAudioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                                      [NSNumber numberWithInteger:128000], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                                      [NSNumber numberWithInteger:44100], AVSampleRateKey,
                                                      channelLayoutAsData, AVChannelLayoutKey,
                                                      [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                                      nil];
            AVAssetWriterInput *input = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:[audioTrack mediaType] outputSettings:compressionAudioSettings];
            [assetWriter addInput:input];

            // Create and save an instance of RWSampleBufferChannel, which will coordinate the work of reading and writing sample buffers
            audioSampleBufferChannel = [[RWSampleBufferChannel alloc] initWithAssetReaderOutput:output assetWriterInput:input];
        }

        if (videoTrack)
        {
            // Decompress to ARGB with the asset reader
            NSDictionary *decompressionVideoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                                        [NSDictionary dictionary], (id)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey,
                                                        nil];
            AVAssetReaderOutput *output = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:videoTrack outputSettings:decompressionVideoSettings];
            [assetReader addOutput:output];

            // Get the format description of the track, to fill in attributes of the video stream that we don't want to change
            CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = NULL;
            NSArray *formatDescriptions = [videoTrack formatDescriptions];
            if ([formatDescriptions count] > 0)
                formatDescription = (CMFormatDescriptionRef)[formatDescriptions objectAtIndex:0];

            // Grab track dimensions from format description
            CGSize trackDimensions = {
                .width = 0.0,
                .height = 0.0,
            };
            if (formatDescription)
                trackDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetPresentationDimensions(formatDescription, false, false);
            else
                trackDimensions = [videoTrack naturalSize];


            // Grab clean aperture, pixel aspect ratio from format description
            NSMutableDictionary *compressionSettings = nil;
            //                                                        [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            //                                                        AVVideoProfileLevelH264Baseline30, AVVideoProfileLevelKey, 
            //                                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:960000], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
            //                                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey,
            //                                                        nil ];
            //NSDictionary *videoSettings = nil;
            if (formatDescription)
            {
                NSDictionary *cleanAperture = nil;
                NSDictionary *pixelAspectRatio = nil;
                CFDictionaryRef cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription = CMFormatDescriptionGetExtension(formatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_CleanAperture);
                if (cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription)
                {
                    cleanAperture = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     CFDictionaryGetValue(cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_CleanApertureWidth), AVVideoCleanApertureWidthKey,
                                     CFDictionaryGetValue(cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_CleanApertureHeight), AVVideoCleanApertureHeightKey,
                                     CFDictionaryGetValue(cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_CleanApertureHorizontalOffset), AVVideoCleanApertureHorizontalOffsetKey,
                                     CFDictionaryGetValue(cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_CleanApertureVerticalOffset), AVVideoCleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey,
                                     nil];
                }
                CFDictionaryRef pixelAspectRatioFromCMFormatDescription = CMFormatDescriptionGetExtension(formatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_PixelAspectRatio);
                if (pixelAspectRatioFromCMFormatDescription)
                {
                    pixelAspectRatio = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        CFDictionaryGetValue(pixelAspectRatioFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_PixelAspectRatioHorizontalSpacing), AVVideoPixelAspectRatioHorizontalSpacingKey,
                                        CFDictionaryGetValue(pixelAspectRatioFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_PixelAspectRatioVerticalSpacing), AVVideoPixelAspectRatioVerticalSpacingKey,
                                        nil];
                }

                if (cleanAperture || pixelAspectRatio)
                {
                    if (cleanAperture)
                        [compressionSettings setObject:cleanAperture forKey:AVVideoCleanApertureKey];
                    if (pixelAspectRatio)
                        [compressionSettings setObject:pixelAspectRatio forKey:AVVideoPixelAspectRatioKey];
                }
            }

            // Compress to H.264 with the asset writer
            NSMutableDictionary *videoSettings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                  AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:trackDimensions.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:trackDimensions.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                                  nil];
            if (compressionSettings)
                [videoSettings setObject:compressionSettings forKey:AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey];



            AVAssetWriterInput *input = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:[videoTrack mediaType] outputSettings:videoSettings];
            [assetWriter addInput:input];

            // Create and save an instance of RWSampleBufferChannel, which will coordinate the work of reading and writing sample buffers
            videoSampleBufferChannel = [[RWSampleBufferChannel alloc] initWithAssetReaderOutput:output assetWriterInput:input];
        }
    }

    if (outError)
        *outError = localError;

    return success;
}

- (BOOL)startReadingAndWritingReturningError:(NSError **)outError
{
    BOOL success = YES;
    NSError *localError = nil;

    // Instruct the asset reader and asset writer to get ready to do work
    success = [assetReader startReading];
    if (!success)
        localError = [assetReader error];
    if (success)
    {
        success = [assetWriter startWriting];
        if (!success)
            localError = [assetWriter error];
    }

    if (success)
    {
        dispatch_group_t dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create();

        // Start a sample-writing session
        [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:[self timeRange].start];

        // Start reading and writing samples
        if (audioSampleBufferChannel)
        {
            // Only set audio delegate for audio-only assets, else let the video channel drive progress
            id <RWSampleBufferChannelDelegate> delegate = nil;
            if (!videoSampleBufferChannel)
                delegate = self;

            dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroup);
            [audioSampleBufferChannel startWithDelegate:delegate completionHandler:^{
                dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup);
            }];
        }
        if (videoSampleBufferChannel)
        {
            dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroup);
            [videoSampleBufferChannel startWithDelegate:self completionHandler:^{
                dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup);
            }];
        }

        // Set up a callback for when the sample writing is finished
        dispatch_group_notify(dispatchGroup, serializationQueue, ^{
            BOOL finalSuccess = YES;
            NSError *finalError = nil;

            if (cancelled)
            {
                [assetReader cancelReading];
                [assetWriter cancelWriting];
            }
            else
            {
                if ([assetReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusFailed)
                {
                    finalSuccess = NO;
                    finalError = [assetReader error];
                }

                if (finalSuccess)
                {
                    finalSuccess = [assetWriter finishWriting];
                    if (!finalSuccess)
                        finalError = [assetWriter error];
                }
            }

            [self readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:finalSuccess withError:finalError];
        });

        dispatch_release(dispatchGroup);
    }

    if (outError)
        *outError = localError;

    return success;
}

- (void)cancel
{
    self.propgerssView = nil;

    // Dispatch cancellation tasks to the serialization queue to avoid races with setup and teardown
    dispatch_async(serializationQueue, ^{
        [audioSampleBufferChannel cancel];
        [videoSampleBufferChannel cancel];
        cancelled = YES;
    });
}

- (void)readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:(BOOL)success withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s[%d] - success = %d error = %@", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, success, error);

    if (!success)
    {
        [assetReader cancelReading];
        [assetWriter cancelWriting];
    }

    // Tear down ivars
    [assetReader release];
    assetReader = nil;
    [assetWriter release];
    assetWriter = nil;
    [audioSampleBufferChannel release];
    audioSampleBufferChannel = nil;
    [videoSampleBufferChannel release];
    videoSampleBufferChannel = nil;
    cancelled = NO;

    // Dispatch UI-related tasks to the main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (!success)
        {

        }

        [self setWritingSamples:NO];
    });
}

static double progressOfSampleBufferInTimeRange(CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer, CMTimeRange timeRange)
{
    CMTime progressTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
    progressTime = CMTimeSubtract(progressTime, timeRange.start);
    CMTime sampleDuration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer);
    if (CMTIME_IS_NUMERIC(sampleDuration))
        progressTime= CMTimeAdd(progressTime, sampleDuration);
    return CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime) / CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.duration);
}

static void removeARGBColorComponentOfPixelBuffer(CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer, size_t componentIndex)
{
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

    size_t bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
    size_t bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);
    static const size_t bytesPerPixel = 4;  // constant for ARGB pixel format
    unsigned char *base = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);

    for (size_t row = 0; row < bufferHeight; ++row)
    {       
        for (size_t column = 0; column < bufferWidth; ++column)
        {
            unsigned char *pixel = base + (row * bytesPerRow) + (column * bytesPerPixel);
            pixel[componentIndex] = 0;
        }
    }

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
}

+ (size_t)componentIndexFromFilterTag:(NSInteger)filterTag
{
    return (size_t)filterTag;  // we set up the tags in the popup button to correspond directly with the index they modify
}

- (void)sampleBufferChannel:(RWSampleBufferChannel *)sampleBufferChannel didReadSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;

    // Calculate progress (scale of 0.0 to 1.0)
    double progress = progressOfSampleBufferInTimeRange(sampleBuffer, [self timeRange]);
    NSLog(@"%s[%d] - progress = %f", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, progress);


    // Grab the pixel buffer from the sample buffer, if possible
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    if (imageBuffer && (CFGetTypeID(imageBuffer) == CVPixelBufferGetTypeID()))
    {
        pixelBuffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)imageBuffer;
        if (filterTag >= 0)  // -1 means "no filtering, please"
            removeARGBColorComponentOfPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, [[self class] componentIndexFromFilterTag:filterTag]);
    }   
}

@end


@interface RWSampleBufferChannel ()
- (void)callCompletionHandlerIfNecessary;  // always called on the serialization queue
@end

@implementation RWSampleBufferChannel

- (id)initWithAssetReaderOutput:(AVAssetReaderOutput *)localAssetReaderOutput assetWriterInput:(AVAssetWriterInput *)localAssetWriterInput
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        assetReaderOutput = [localAssetReaderOutput retain];
        assetWriterInput = [localAssetWriterInput retain];

        finished = NO;
        NSString *serializationQueueDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ serialization queue", self];
        serializationQueue = dispatch_queue_create([serializationQueueDescription UTF8String], NULL);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [assetReaderOutput release];
    [assetWriterInput release];
    if (serializationQueue)
        dispatch_release(serializationQueue);
    [completionHandler release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSString *)mediaType
{
    return [assetReaderOutput mediaType];
}

- (void)startWithDelegate:(id <RWSampleBufferChannelDelegate>)delegate completionHandler:(dispatch_block_t)localCompletionHandler
{
    completionHandler = [localCompletionHandler copy];  // released in -callCompletionHandlerIfNecessary

    [assetWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:serializationQueue usingBlock:^{
        if (finished)
            return;

        BOOL completedOrFailed = NO;

        // Read samples in a loop as long as the asset writer input is ready
        while ([assetWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData] && !completedOrFailed)
        {
            CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [assetReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
            if (sampleBuffer != NULL)
            {
                if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sampleBufferChannel:didReadSampleBuffer:)])
                    [delegate sampleBufferChannel:self didReadSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

                BOOL success = [assetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
                sampleBuffer = NULL;

                completedOrFailed = !success;
            }
            else
            {
                completedOrFailed = YES;
            }
        }

        if (completedOrFailed)
            [self callCompletionHandlerIfNecessary];
    }];
}

- (void)cancel
{
    dispatch_async(serializationQueue, ^{
        [self callCompletionHandlerIfNecessary];
    });
}

- (void)callCompletionHandlerIfNecessary
{
    // Set state to mark that we no longer need to call the completion handler, grab the completion handler, and clear out the ivar
    BOOL oldFinished = finished;
    finished = YES;

    if (oldFinished == NO)
    {
        [assetWriterInput markAsFinished];  // let the asset writer know that we will not be appending any more samples to this input

        dispatch_block_t localCompletionHandler = [completionHandler retain];
        [completionHandler release];
        completionHandler = nil;

        if (localCompletionHandler)
        {
            localCompletionHandler();
            [localCompletionHandler release];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey It was for a long while, but I end up with good solution and it may help someone in future

my code:

```
-(void) compressVideo
{
asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoUrl options:nil];
exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

 NSLog(@" %@",  [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:asset]);
 NSLog(@" %@",  exportSession.supportedFileTypes);


 NSLog(@"----------------------------------------- convert to mp4");
 NSLog(@" %@",  exportSession.supportedFileTypes);

exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
exportSession.outputURL = [self outputVideoPath:@"outPut" ext:@"mp4"];

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
     ICQLog(@" exportSession.status = %d exportSession.error = %@",  exportSession.status, exportSession.error);

    if ( exportSession && (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) )
    {
         ICQLog(@" exportSession.outputURL = %@",  exportSession.outputURL);

        // we need to remove temporary files
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:videoUrl error:NULL];
        [videoUrl release];
        videoUrl = [exportSession.outputURL retain];

    }
    else 
    {
        //TODO - report error
    }

    [exportSession release], exportSession = nil;
    [asset release], asset = nil;
}];
```

Comment: I tried this and AVFoundation complained saying that my pro-res video is not compatible with mp4.  Do you know of a different way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with the trans-wrap stuff, I haven't got my head into this.

Is the main priority to get the file output as a .mp4 without having to reprocess it? If it is then just use .mp4 as the file extension of the movie clip that was output by you code and this should work fine. I have used this approach today and it works. i didn't have to convert it from .mov to .mp4 because essentially a .mp4 file is the same as a .mov file with some additional standards based functionality.

Hope this is of help.

Comment: You can do this, but they won't play on Android devices.

Comment: Hey you can see my code below - it make the compression and repacking to mp4 format and it play on Android devices

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used.

- (BOOL)encodeVideo:(NSURL *)videoURL
  {
      AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];

  ```
  // Create the composition and tracks
  AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
  AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
  AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
  NSArray *assetVideoTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
  if (assetVideoTracks.count <= 0)
  {
          NSLog(@"Error reading the transformed video track");
          return NO;
  }

  // Insert the tracks in the composition's tracks
  AVAssetTrack *assetVideoTrack = [assetVideoTracks firstObject];
  [videoTrack insertTimeRange:assetVideoTrack.timeRange ofTrack:assetVideoTrack atTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) error:nil];
  [videoTrack setPreferredTransform:assetVideoTrack.preferredTransform];

  AVAssetTrack *assetAudioTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
  [audioTrack insertTimeRange:assetAudioTrack.timeRange ofTrack:assetAudioTrack atTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) error:nil];

  // Export to mp4
  NSString *mp4Quality = [MGPublic isIOSAbove:@"6.0"] ? AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality : AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough;
  NSString *exportPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp4",
                                   [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/tmp"],
                                   [BSCommon uuidString]];

  NSURL *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];
  AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:mp4Quality];
  exportSession.outputURL = exportUrl;
  CMTime start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 0);
  CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake(start, [asset duration]);
  exportSession.timeRange = range;
  exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
  [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
          switch ([exportSession status])
          {
          case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                  NSLog(@"MP4 Successful!");
                  break;
          case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                  NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
                  break;
          case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                  NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                  break;
          default:
                  break;
          }
  }];

  return YES;
  ```

  }